# Tab navigator adding header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using React navigation. I want to add headers to my tab navigator components. How can I do that?

Tab navigation function

```
const TabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Welcome} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Stack navigator function

```
<Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="SignIn">
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigation" component={TabNavigation}/>
 <Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: You can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

Comment: My goal is not to get the menus to the top. Just adding headers to menus. Menus should stay on the bottom

Comment: You can use `tabBarPosition="bottom"` prop to set it bottom and then use Stack.Screen options prop to customize the header

Comment: You're saying for material bottom right? @Andry

Comment: Was referring to material-top-tab-navigator, that is what I am using personally for bottom tabs. Also posted an directing answer @Gucal

Answer (score -1):

You can customize your header dynamically in Stack Navigation screen [options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#options) prop. For example you can create custom functions like `getTitle` to determine title dynamically depending on your route.

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name="TabNavigation"
    component={TabNavigation}
    options={({ route }) => ({ 
        //title: getTitle(route),
        //headerStyle: styles.headerStyle
        //headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle
    })}
/>
```

Comment: Can't variable error for getTitle. getTitle is also not included in the document.

Comment: This is the function you can implement yourself, updated description @Gucal

Comment: this is not a answer for this question